# Cannot connect to MySql through R. (Error with host argument)

Tags: mysql, r

I opened SQL clicked on the database I wanted (named bb) then at the top I choose Database then Manage Connections.  This showed me the Hostname as 127.0.0.1, port as 3306, username as root and there should be no password.  Plugged that into to dbConnect and it is giving the following errors

This is the code I have and I am trying to open a connection.

```
> con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "bb", username = "root", host = 
"127.0.0.1:3306")
    Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
    Failed to connect to database: Error: Unknown MySQL Server Host 
    '127.0.0.1:3306' (11001)
> con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "bb", username = "root", host = 
"127.0.0.1", port = 3306)
    Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
    Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on    
    '127.0.0.1' (0)
> con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "bb", username = "root", host = 
"127.0.0.1", port = "3306")
    Error in .local(drv, ...) : Argument port must be an integer value
```

All of them are returning errors.  I don't know why it is not working.
Please Help and Thank you.

Comment: Try `host = "localhost"` and leave off the `port` argument

Comment: This is the result I got.                                                                                  > con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "bb", username = "root", host = "localhost")
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (0)